# How to get multiple VM metric (Percentage CPU, DIisk Read Operations/sec, Memory etc .. platform metrics) details in a single API Call for a single VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, metrics, rest, platform

Like from URL GET
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmname}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage%20CPU&timespan=2018-06-05T03:00:00Z/2018-06-07T03:00:00Z](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%7Bvmname%7D/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage%20CPU&timespan=2018-06-05T03:00:00Z/2018-06-07T03:00:00Z)

We can fetch only one metric "percentage CPU" at a time.

I want to fetch percentage CPU, Memory, disk network, etc metrics in one API call for a single VM.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify all metrics you want to query by `metricnames` param separate by `,` in request URL just as below:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmname}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage CPU,Disk Read Bytes,Disk Write Bytes,Network In,Network Out&timespan=2018-06-05T03:00:00Z/2018-06-07T03:00:00Z
```

Result:

[image]

All natively supported metrics are:

```
Percentage CPU,Network In,Network Out,Disk Read Bytes,Disk Write Bytes,Disk Read Operations/Sec,Disk Write Operations/Sec,CPU Credits Remaining,CPU Credits Consumed,Data Disk Read Bytes/sec,Data Disk Write Bytes/sec,Data Disk Read Operations/Sec,Data Disk Write Operations/Sec,Data Disk Queue Depth,Data Disk Bandwidth Consumed Percentage,Data Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage,Data Disk Target Bandwidth,Data Disk Target IOPS,Data Disk Max Burst Bandwidth,Data Disk Max Burst IOPS,Data Disk Used Burst BPS Credits Percentage,Data Disk Used Burst IO Credits Percentage,OS Disk Read Bytes/sec,OS Disk Write Bytes/sec,OS Disk Read Operations/Sec,OS Disk Write Operations/Sec,OS Disk Queue Depth,OS Disk Bandwidth Consumed Percentage,OS Disk IOPS Consumed Percentage,OS Disk Target Bandwidth,OS Disk Target IOPS,OS Disk Max Burst Bandwidth,OS Disk Max Burst IOPS,OS Disk Used Burst BPS Credits Percentage,OS Disk Used Burst IO Credits Percentage,Inbound Flows,Outbound Flows,Inbound Flows Maximum Creation Rate,Outbound Flows Maximum Creation Rate,Premium Data Disk Cache Read Hit,Premium Data Disk Cache Read Miss,Premium OS Disk Cache Read Hit,Premium OS Disk Cache Read Miss,VM Cached Bandwidth Consumed Percentage,VM Cached IOPS Consumed Percentage,VM Uncached Bandwidth Consumed Percentage,VM Uncached IOPS Consumed Percentage,Network In Total,Network Out Total
```

If you want to get memory-related metrics, [see this post](https://heranonazure.wordpress.com/2019/03/13/azure-vm-memory-monitoring/).

Comment: Can we also fetch the data aggregated by average as well as Max in the same call? I tried this, but not working for me.

Comment: Only aggregation = average is working for me. Unable to fetch the data for Max or Min or Sum or all(separated by , )

Comment: Just try `aggregation = maximum` , official doc seems not has been updated yet

Comment: @user3726056,btw, if my post is helpful, pls click the checkmark beside my post to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Azure allows to fetch multiple metrics as mentioned on its documents

[image: metrics_names]

Image has been picked form Azure document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list

***Note:** Although it allows multiple metrics but with a limit cap of 20. It would give an error if more than 20 metrics name are specified
"Requested metrics count: 21 bigger than allowed max: 20"